# JSON Enum Schema issue - Correct me with valid schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have following JSON Payload where i am trying to add ENUM type Value for one of the element.

```
{
  "firstName" : "firstName",
  "lastName" : "lastName",
  "systemIds" : [ {
    "systemName" : "SAP",
    "systemId" : "99c27c63-e0b6-4585-8675-7aa3811eb4c3"
  }, {
    "systemName" : "SFDC",
    "systemId" : "b65abf1d-825d-4ee3-9791-02d2cdd5e6f4"
  }, {
    "systemName" : "MONGODB",
    "systemId" : "18e50430-8589-42d6-8477-58839a8bf202"
  } ]
}
```

And here is my Schema which i tried to modify after it was auto generated using this website. http://jsonschema.net/#/

I added manually ENUM types as per my expectation here. Please correct what's wrong with this SCHEMA.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/firstName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/lastName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "systemIds": {
      "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds",
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": false,
      "additionalItems": true,
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "systemName": {
                "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0/systemName",
                "type": { "enum": [ "SAP", "MONGODB", "ERP", "SFDC" ] }
              },"required": ["type"],
              "systemId": {
                "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0/systemId",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok _what_ is wrong with it? Don't make us guess.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong here. I am new to JSON schema creation and i used this link to validate this JSON Schema - http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/# this gives me following errors. data.properties.* referenced schema does not match [object Object]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The the schema for the array items doesn't look right.

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "systemName": {
          "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0/systemName",
          "type": {
            "enum": [
              "SAP",
              "MONGODB",
              "ERP",
              "SFDC"
            ]
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "type"
        ],
        "systemId": {
          "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0/systemId",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You stated that there should be a `"required"` property but you put in an invalid schema.  That needs to be removed.  But perhaps you meant that the `"type"` property is required somewhere and is misplaced.  I don't see any relation.

The `"systemName"` property is a string type with values that should be within that enumeration.  The schema there is invalid.

This should work for you:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/firstName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/lastName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "systemIds": {
      "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds",
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": false,
      "additionalItems": true,
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "systemName": {
                "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0/systemName",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [ "SAP", "MONGODB", "ERP", "SFDC" ]
              },
              "systemId": {
                "id": "http://abcd.com/schemas/customerInfo/systemIds/0/systemId",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for correcting it. And just to make sure here if i use "anyOf" here that means any of this value from ENUM list i can assign to "systemName" element right?

Comment: No, by using `"anyOf"` here, you're stating that the array items can be any any type in the array of schemas provided, regardless of index in the array.  With arrays, you have control over what items appear in what index but that is not being used here.

Comment: I am looking for right value here then. Take a look on my Request Payload of JSON as part of my question and suggest me right value for it then.

Comment: The schema is good, but one thing you want to do is get rid of all the spurious `id`s; this schema is non reusable as it is (by other schemas). Keep the id at the top only.